# Beacon connectivity not working when app is in sleep mode

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, wakelock, android-ibeacon

I am working on ibeacon and it is working perfectly fine when app is in foreground or when device is awake but app is in background. The issue is when device goes to sleep mode. iBeacon default methods gets stopped and start working  as soon as device awakes. It does not matter whether app is in foreground or background.

I tried wake lock and alarm manager. But failed. Please suggest

Comment: Did you tried to implement the logic in sticky background service ?

Comment: No, it is iBeacon and they are having there own SDK

Comment: Yeah but they will respond when your activity is alive, you need to move the logic in background sticky service so it will remain alive and you will receive the info I had same problem and moved ibeacon code to service.

Comment: can you please share some reference code here ?

Comment: read about services 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: No its not useful. Neither did enter not didExit methods are called in sleep mode

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152266/discussion-between-faraz-ahmed-and-harneet).

Comment: Beacon background support on Android all depends on the SDK you are using.    I would suggest you check out the open source Android Beacon Library as it is designed to work in the background on many devices and OS versions. http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/  (Full disclosure:  I am the lead developer.)

Comment: Using ibeacons, unable to add start monitoring regions () , BlueCatsSDKService is throwing exception as it is getting null context